# Body content covers navbar drop down

Tags: html, css, position

Im creating a responsive website so that when the website is used as a mobile they can check the box which will display a drop down menu of the navbar. This is currently working except when the box is clicked the drop down nav bar goes behind my banner content. Does anyone know why this is? Very stuck currently.

HTML CODE:

```
  <div class = "wrapper">

  <header>
  <div class = "header">
  <h2 class = "logo">Haukai Restaurant</h2>
  <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk">
  <label for = "chk" class = "show-menu-btn">
    <i class = "fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </label>

<ul class = "menu-nav">
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
  <a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
  <a href="hours.html">Hours</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <label for = "chk" class = "hide-menu-btn">
    <i class = "fas fa-times"></i>
  </label>

</ul>
```

```
   <section class="banner">
    <div class="img-container">
      <div class="inner-container"> 
        <h1>Haukai Restaurant</h1>
        <h2>Bringing Maori culture and kai to you</h2>
        <a class="btn" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
        <a class="btn" href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
        <a class="btn" href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
        <div class = "about-us">
          <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
          <div class = "about-us-content">
          <h2>About us</h2>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. 
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
     
   </section>
   </div>
   </body>
```

CSS CODE:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  }

 /* Home Page */

 body {
  background: #000;
  min-height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
  }

 .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  }

  /* Header */

  .header {
   height: 100px;
   background: #000;
   padding: 0 20px;
   color: #fff;
    }

  .logo {
   line-height: 100px;
   float: left;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   }

  .menu-nav {
  float: right;
   line-height: 100px;
   }

  .menu-nav a {
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 10px;
   transition: 0.4s;
   }

  .show-menu-btn,
  .hide-menu-btn {
   transition: 0.4s;
   font-size: 30px;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
  }

   .show-menu-btn {
    float: right;
  }

  .show-menu-btn i {
   line-height: 100px;
  }

  .menu a:hover,
  .show-menu-btn:hover,
  .hide-menu-btn:hover {
    color: #feca1d;
  }

  #chk {
    position: absolute;
   visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -1111;
  }

  .menu-content {
   padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(insiderest.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  }


 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .show-menu-btn,
 .hide-menu-btn {
  display: block;
}

 .menu-nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #333;
 right: -100%;
 top: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 80px 0;
 line-height: normal;
 transition: 0.7s;
  }

 .menu-nav a {
   display: block;
   padding: 20px;
  }

  .hide-menu-btn {
   position: absolute;
   top: 40px;
   right: 40px;
   }

  #chk:checked ~ .menu-nav {
  right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does adding a z-index of 2 to the .menu-nav class help?

Comment: Graeme this didnt work either the nav is still going behind my banner

Comment: To clarify you put it in _both_ .menu-nav classes? Also to clarify is only a problem with the mobile css inside of  `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {` ?

Comment: Yup I only want the nav to go down vertically like this with a max-width of 600px. What do you mean by both .menu-nav classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using media queries. You have one `.menu-nav` above the query and one inside of the media query `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {`

z-indexes are only counted if the position is fixed, relative, absolute, sticky, etc. The first css class will dismiss the z-index because it has no position property. [Replacing the float with position relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579753/css-floating-with-overlap) could work.

```
.menu-nav {
   float: right;
   line-height: 100px;
}
```

or, alternatively it should work to add the z-index to the media query .menu-nav class.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .menu-nav {
       position: fixed;
       z-index:2;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       background: #333;
       right: -100%;
       top: 0;
       text-align: center;
       padding: 80px 0;
       line-height: normal;
       transition: 0.7s;
     }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work.

```
.menu-nav {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. Didn't change it from going behind my banner.